# Using the UISplitViewController in iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, swift3

I have been going through this tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/94443/uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) however when you try to update the code to Swift 3 syntax you get errors. I do not know enough Swift to fix them myself.

[image][image]

The bottom line is I am trying to find a tutorial to help me use the `UISplitViewController` in Swift 3. I tried picking apart Xcode's Master Detail Application but I was not able to figure it out.

EDIT: I was able to get rid of the errors, however the app does not function correctly i.e. the Detail view of the app should change to the corresponding master view item selected. It does not do this. It stays on one view.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this with some fiddling to the syntax. You need to write the init coder part as 'required init?' with a question mark or else you get an error and possibly add an exclamation mark somewhere in the Tableview DidSelectRow part.

Comment: This sounds very dangerous. You should make sure you know exactly what your fix is doing before implementing it, especially if you're "fixing" it by using exclamation marks. In this case, you've marked you initializer as failable, meaning it is allowed to return `nil`. If you never want this to happen, you should handle the case of `super.init` returning `nil`.

Comment: I am a noob and this is all just for my learning. Thank you for that I had no idea. Could elaborate more on what you mean or point me to information on it. I only marked this as a "fix" becasue it compiled and ran as expected.

Comment: You can read more about failable initializers here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID224. Basically, you can't have a failable initializer inside a non-failable initializer because if the inner initialization fails, the outer `init` has no way of handling it. That's why you have to explicitly handle it internally (or mark the outer `init` as failable, which may not be what you want). You probably don't even want to implement `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` at all.

Comment: I hit the character limit, but what you probably want to do is write a separate `init()` that takes no arguments, seeing as how you don't use the `coder` at all. Xcode will tell you that you need `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, so just accept the quick-fix it provides.

Comment: Ok cool, I will look into that. Like I said above I was just following a tutorial and thats how they showed doing it. Thank you